# org.springframework.util.Assert shows in my surefire reports as an error, when in fact it should be a failure

Tags: java, spring, junit

However when using the nromal junit assertions, the failures are reported correctly.

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
```

Correctly shows up as a failure.

is there anything I can do to make sure spring Assert shows up as failure as well as the normal junit asserts ?

To clarify this

```
Assert.notNull(null);
```

Shows as an error in test report, and not a failure.

Comment: Well, one reason why surefire report treats these 2 differentlly is that while JUnit Assert.assertNotNull trows an AssertionError when the condition is not fullfilled, Spring Assert.notNull throws an IllegalArgumentException which is treated by surefire as a code issue in your test rather than a failed assert

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the wrong `Assert` class in your unit tests:

- the `org.junit.Assert` class is for use in unit tests
- the `org.springframework.util.Assert` class is for use in runtime code.

And the practical difference is that they throw different exceptions.

If your unit test is testing whether (say) your bean's `afterPropertiesSet()` method is calling `org.springframework.util.Assert` correctly, then this is not a simple JUnit style assertion.  Rather, it is a test that `IllegalArgumentException` is being thrown, and should be tested in the same way that you would test for (say) `IOException` being thrown at the appropriate point.